# Chrome Browser (on Android) Precise GeoLocation

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, geolocation

```
function getLocation() {
    var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 500
    };

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, error, options);
    } else {

    }
}
```

I am using the above code to get the location on a webpage.  On an iPhone/Safari browser, I get 14 decimal places but only 7 decimal places on Android/Chrome.  How can I get more precise location on the Andriod?

Answer (score 0):

Did some tests in Firefox, on laptop and mobile:

Both of them return various precision, based on my location they differ even in lat & long fields during the same request. Looks to me the precision is rounded when its not relevant.

- [w3c geolocation test requests](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation)
- [w3c open geolocation docs](https://w3c.github.io/geolocation-api/#introduction)

What you have to take in consideration is that the html Geolocation API not necessarily requests coordinates via the GPS module, but often chooses IP routes because of power consumption. Which is also very accurate.

Precision within the 5th decimal point is enough to give you a 10meter resolution.
Strict use of GPS is not really possible, but can be "prioritized". You already did that in your code by requesting with options. [More info](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude)

what you could do, is notify the user of your app when there's or isn't GPS available.
Or, use a different api, for example: [mapquest](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/open/geocoding-api/)

Is there a possibility that your phone's GPS location service is disabled, and that you're only connected via Cellular network? That would explain why your location points to 1.5 blocks away. The nearest Cellular tower?

Comment: On iOS, the lat/long pins the map very accurately.  On Android, because there are not enough significant digits, the pin can be up to a 1.5 blocks from actual location.  An example is 33.51554157215498 vs 33.5154456 would be some what acceptable but when the location is more then 1+ block away, that is not.

Comment: What you have to take in consideration is that the html Geolocation API not necessarily requests GPS coordinates, but often IP routes.
Precision within the 5th decimal point is enough to give you a 10meter resolution. 

Check out this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude

Comment: Gotcha.  But on the Android, the function returns a lat/long that places the user up to 1.5 blocks away from the actual location.  So instead of get more decimal places, how can I get more accurate lat/long?